# What is the meaning of itemprop="contentUrl" in HTML img tag?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, html, schema.org

I see a attribute called **itemprop="contentUrl"** in a image. But I don't understand the meaning of this.

Answer (score 1):

contentUrl is one of the properties of ImageObject which helps define an image in Structured Data using schema.org:

https://schema.org/ImageObject